# Nativescript how to hide tabstrip bar at bottom of screen

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to hide navigation bar from bottom of the screen in one of the screen. I tired to set it by css

```
visibility:collapse;
```

and programatically

```
 let tab: TabStrip = this.page.getViewById("btm-tab");
        tab.visibility = Visibility.collapse;
 //and tried this as well 
 //tab.viewController.tabBar.hidden = true;
```

but it works on android but on IOS it shows white space at that place where bar was there. How can collapse tabstrip on IOS as well. I am using angular for nativescript. I have gone through some of the solution provided on stackoverflow but it didn't worked for me.

[image]

Comment: @FailsalAhmed did you try setting height to 0 explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that is not "collapse" and the correct line would be

```
visibility: collapsed;
```

Test it and tell me later :)